# Missed rewarding a bounty on time

Tags: support, bounty

I opened a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229335/add-video-to-users-favorite-like-playlist-on-youtube) and missed rewarding the answer in time. So the bounty was auto-rewarded but only **half** of the points were given to this user. The bounty was for 200 points originally.

Is there any way for the moderators to resolve this so that the user can receive their full bounty points?

This is by far *the* most complete answer on this topic here and shouldn't be rewarded any less because of me being inactivate the past few days.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there any way I can bounty the user with another 100 points via a *new* bounty? I don't mind losing 100 points on it at all. When I clicked the bounty button, I only seemed to be able to bounty 400+ points...

Comment: No, there is no way for you to award a smaller bounty at this point.

Comment: You get notifications 3 days before the bounty runs out, the day before, and the same day (if I remember correctly). You can award the bounty at any time after the first day that it is active, and you even have another 24 hours after the bounty ends. If you aren't on Stack Overflow at any time during that, (in which case, you probably should have waited to post the bounty), you can also get e-mail notifications. Is it really a problem for Stack Overflow if you didn't take advantage of any of this?

Comment: @zondo I am well aware of all of that and never claimed that the current system is poor in any way.

Comment: My point is that the current system assumes that if you didn't award the bounty at any of your numerous opportunities, you probably don't intend to. Adding you yet one more opportunity seems like a useless waste of time.

Comment: you may find the extra attention from the meta effect brings some additional upvotes to the answer anyway.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way this can be corrected, moderators can't help here.

You can start a *new* bounty and award that to the same answer, but we can't undo the auto-award or award the other half. Take into account a new bounty on the same question will have to be double the value of the previous bounty (up to a limit of 500 points).

Comment: In this case, maybe this should be a feature request...?

Comment: Has anyone offered a feature request to allow users to award the full bounty to a user who has already received half the bounty? May be a nice addition to prevent these types of cases (Although, I'm not sure if the amount of coding would be worth it).

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: sorry, I don't think such a feature request would stand much chance. You were given plenty of opportunity to award before the bounty expiration, and during the roughly 24h grace period after.

Comment: Ah, I have another potential option though. I could bounty 100 points on one of this user's *other* answer and just reward him the points that way. Kind of abstract solution but I guess it works? :D

Comment: @FrankerZ: I'd be opposed to that, as it would allow for the bounty awarder to indefinitely postpone awarding half the bounty, which is open to abuse (update your answer please, or I won't release the other half of the bounty).

Comment: @HenrikPetterson then I wouldn't be surprised if the community notices and flags it with something like: "this user seems to be bountying his rep to this other user..." :)